# How can I check integrity of a extracted zImage?

Tags: arm, qemu

```
$ binwalk -e linux_image.img
DECIMAL HEXADECIMAL DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0 0x0 Android bootimg, kernel size: 6897653 bytes, kernel addr: 0x81C08000, ramdisk size: 5959520 bytes, ramdisk addr: 0x81C08000, product name: ""
2048 0x800 Linux kernel ARM boot executable zImage (little-endian)
18479 0x482F gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, last modified: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (null date)
6761720 0x672CF8 device tree image (dtb)
6883304 0x6907E8 Unix path: /dev/block/platform/soc/7824900.sdhci/by-name/vendor
6899712 0x694800 gzip compressed data, maximum compression, has original file name: "rootfs.cpio", from Unix, last modified: 2019-04-06 00:42:26
9706949 0x941DC5 MySQL ISAM compressed data file Version 11

$ dd if=linux_image.img of=vmlinuz bs=1 skip=2048 count=6897653

$ file vmlinuz
vmlinuz: Linux kernel ARM boot executable zImage (little-endian)

$ dd if=vmlinuz bs=1 skip=$(LC_ALL=C grep -a -b -o $'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00' vmlinuz-3.18.66-perf | head -n 1 | cut -d ':' -f 1) | zcat | grep -a 'Linux version'
Linux version 3.18.66 (build@test) (gcc version 4.9.3 (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Apr 1 13:16:33 PDT 2018
```

Running 'qemu-system-arm.exe -machine vexpress-a9 -cpu cortex-a7 -smp 4 -kernel vmlinuz' blank screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pull a random Arm Linux kernel (including Android) from somewhere and try to run it on anything other than the hardware that it is intended to boot on, the expected result is that it crashes very early in bootup without being able to output anything to screen or serial port, ie you get a black screen  and nothing happens. The most likely situation here is that your image is fine and not corrupt, it's just not built to run on the vexpress-a9 board you're running it on.

In the unlikely event that this really is a kernel built for the vexpress-a9, the next problem you have is that you haven't passed QEMU a device tree blob via the -dtb option. Modern Linux kernels don't hardcode all the information about the boards they can run on, but instead expect the bootloader (which is QEMU in this case) to pass them a data file which provides information about where all the devices are for the board. If you don't do that, then the result is the same as above: kernel crashes very early in bootup without being able to output any information, so black screen.

Comment: This kernel was compiled to a Qualcomm APQ8009 - Cortex A7... Can't run on qemu? do i need to compile another kernel to run the original initrd?

Comment: Yes, you won't be able to run that kernel on QEMU because it has no models of that Qualcomm SoC or devices. (The CPU model doesn't matter so much, it's the devices.) You'll need a kernel that's built to run on the board model you're trying to use.